# Is one JavaScript second really one second?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two functions, that in theory should show the same time. They do show the same time for some time, but they come out of sync rather quickly.

The servertime function is the following:

```
function servertime() {
            <?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London")?>
            var hours = parseInt(<?php echo date("H");?>);
            var mins = parseInt(<?php echo date("i");?>);
            var secs = parseInt(<?php echo date("s");?>);
            var interval = setInterval(function() {increment() }, 1000);
            function increment() {
                if (secs == 59) {
                    secs = 0;
                    if (mins == 59) {
                        mins = 0;
                        if (hours == 23) {
                            hours = 00;
                        }
                        else {
                            hours = hours + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        mins = mins + 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    secs = secs + 1;
                }
                if (String(hours).length == 1) {
                    hoursprint = "0" + hours;
                }
                else {
                    hoursprint = hours;
                }
                if (String(mins).length == 1) {
                    minsprint = "0" + mins;
                }
                else {
                    minsprint = mins;
                }
                if (String(secs).length == 1) {
                    secsprint = "0" + secs;
                }
                else {
                    secsprint = secs
                }
                var result = hoursprint + ":" + minsprint + ":" + secsprint;
                document.getElementById("server-time").innerHTML = "<p>" + result +"</p>";
            }
        }
        servertime();
```

The clienttime function is the following:

```
function clienttime() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {increment() }, 1000);
            function increment(){
                var i = new Date();
                var hours = String(i.getHours());
                var mins = String(i.getMinutes());
                var secs = String(i.getSeconds());
                if (hours.length == 1) {
                    hours = "0" + hours
                }
                if (mins.length == 1) {
                    mins = "0" + mins
                }
                if (secs.length == 1) {
                    secs = "0" + secs
                }
                var result = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
                document.getElementById("client-time").innerHTML = "<p>" + result +"</p>";
            }

        }
        clienttime();
```

Since the latter fetches the new js time every second, it stays in sync with the actual time.

Why does the server time function not stay in sync?
Am I making a simple mistake?
Is one JavaScript second really one second?

Comment: Just a pro tip, you can change `var interval = setInterval(function() {increment() }, 1000);` -> `var interval = setInterval(increment, 1000);` If you dont need to send arguments or preserve/pass a context to the function in set Timeout/setInterval you can simple pass the function as the first argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval does  not execute every XX seconds. It rather executes every now and then. This highly depends on your scripts runtime. The longer it needs to finish, the more desynced you get.

To accomodate this, you need to save the time of your last run and then setTimeout to a value 1 seconds - runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1. `server-time` is a misnomer
2. It takes time for a function to execute
3. `setinterval` means that the function will execute some time after one second. Depends on what else the OS etc is doing.

Therefore you need to call `new Date()` instead of trying to extrapolate it.